# I can't get/list files in Kotlin / Android Studio, only directories

Tags: android, file, kotlin, directory

Initially the problem is that I could not find the Mp3 that I was trying to play, finally I have summarized the problem by debugging the content of a File value.

```
val files = File("/sdcard/)
```

This is what I get when debugging

[debugging results and folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyfhm.png)

It shows the "NewFolder" folder that I created in the emulator. However, the "NewTextFile.txt" file does not appear. Nor does the Documents folder appear as a dropdown where I created a second "NewTextFile.txt"

In AndroidManifest.xml I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

**EDIT:**

**I have run the application on a physical device and it works fine, it shows files, it seems that the problem is in the emulator**

Comment: have you treid using `files.listFiles()`? it should return list of files

Comment: @Stachu yes, I get exactly the same, an array of folders. This is how I was using it, so I realized that when looping through the list of any folder none had the "isFile" property

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem using Kotlin in Android studio the function below only returns directories even on a device.

```
fun displayFiles(view: View) {
    var fNames = ""
    val directoryPath = "/storage/emulated/0/john/"
    File(directoryPath).walkTopDown().forEach {
        fNames += it
        fNames += "\n"
        
    }
    textView.text = fNames
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing your app on mobile devices rather than an emulator. just restart your devices.